# Java Hibernate not rollback transaction when failed because duplicate keys in db

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I'm using transaction of hiberante , in the transaction I have persist() to db ,
I want to avoid the transaction from rollback if it's failed because persist of duplicate rows .
Here is my code :

```
db.getTransaction().begin;

for (Item item : itemList) {
    try{
        //If duplicate key - don't fail the transaction  
        db.persist(item);
       }
       catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
}

db.commit();
```

Is it possible?
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Is a bit risky for many reason, but you can always catch ConstraintViolationException (which is the duplicate key exception) separately and act accordingly.

Comment: you should put this attribute: noRollbackFor = ConstraintViolationException.class in your @Transactional declaration of the called method.

Comment: problem is the exception is thrown originally by the database. You're going to need to flush before the transaction ends. So immediately after the persist do a flush